# How to construct a query based URL in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app that takes a search string and returns results in one route : `hosts.abc.com:3000`. The url doesn't change.

I want the search to be reflected in the url so I can share the link and users don't have to make all selection in the form fields.

`eg: hosts.abc.com:3000/?type=all&query=coins`

Is it possible to do this using react-router ?

Comment: It is possible, what do you have problem with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To construct such query you could use native browser [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.append("type", "all");
searchParams.append("query", "coins");
searchParams.toString(); // "type=all&query=coins"

// update browser url
this.props.history.push('/current/route/?' + searchParams.toString());
// or
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/current/route/',
  search: searchParams.toString()
})
```

But if you want better support [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) is a similar option.

Comment: This is much harder than i thought. the history.push does add it to the url, But when I visit the url ,say,  hosts.abc.com:3000/?type=all&query=coins  Its just showing the base page hosts.abc.com:3000/ . How can i perform call the search function?

Comment: Also, I want /home and /home/:query in my routes file, This is leading to same content being displayed twice

Comment: had to use componentDidMount  method to parse parameters and us an if condition to not set if the query is already present in url